# How do I setup a git project for COBOL on z/OS?

Tags: git, cobol, zos

I have a git project that contains mostly z/OS COBOL source code.

When I clone it onto my z/OS system using:

```
git clone myproject
```

I noticed that all of the cloned files are in ASCII (ISO8859-1). Is there a way to keep the working tree in EBCDIC 1047 on z/OS?

`chtag -p` yields the following:

```
t ISO8859-1    T=on  hello.cob
```

In the meantime, I am currently converting the files using iconv, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 5):

For a long time Git has had the gitattributes which is the starting point for the answer to this question. You can read more about it in the Git docs, [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes).

z/OS behaves a bit different in this aspect compared to what you will find in the documentation. There is a reason for it though. While the Git docs mention `working-tree-encoding` you should be using `zos-working-tree-encoding` to specify IBM-1047 instead. This was originally developed by Rocket but has since been taken over into other versions as well (see Mike's comment below). It is documented here: https://docs.rocketsoftware.com/bundle/openappdev_ug_20/page/brb1683803214347.html

I don't know this for sure but my understanding is that this way a Git checkout on a non-z/OS host doesn't run into issues when it is trying to convert your files into an EBCDIC code page. If you are sure that your project won't be checked out on a non-z/OS system you could also use `working-tree-encoding`.

A sample .gitattributes file for your case would look like this:

```
*.cob        zos-working-tree-encoding=ibm-1047
```

The .gitattributes file must be in UTF-8 (or ISO8859-1 but try to stick to UTF-8.)

Note: You might find some examples from IBM which also include the git-encoding parameter to specify how Git handles files internally. This should not be used anymore and defaults to UTF-8 (also on z/OS). It is described by Rocket [here](https://docs.rocketsoftware.com/bundle/openappdev_ug_20/page/pxg1649959066690.html).

Note 2: Out of personal experience IBM-1047 is often times not enough as it doesn't include the € sign which is why we tend to use the national code page like ibm-1141 (over here in Germany). For the rest of the world this is likely not interesting.

Comment: Upvoted, but all EBCDIC sets I ever used, including 1047, most certainly do have the dollar sign at `5B`.

Comment: @jthill thanks for pointing this out. I double checked and that is only an issue with the € sign which is converted to 9F. I’ll remove it from the answer.

Comment: Good answer. I would definitely recommend the zos-working-tree-encoding=ibm-1047 over just setting the working-tree-encoding because then it should 'just work' on the different platforms you might want to view the code (github, gitlab, windows, linux, z/OS, etc) and I don't think there is any downside. Note that the enhancements are now in the official 'dev' line and available to anyone - not restricted to Rocket. You can also get the Open Source code at: https://github.com/ZOSOpenTools/gitport